# Simulate strrev() function, crazy output

Tags: c, function, codeblocks

I should simulate the operation of the strrev() function with an inscription from me. However, I don't understand why I have a series of special characters that don't make sense as output until you stop the program completely. I also tried to see if the problem was in the index "i" with the commented line of code, but it's ok. What could be the problem? thanks!

```
void strrev_new(char *s_to_rev) {
  int i = 0;
  int length = 0;
  length = strlen(s_to_rev);
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    s_to_rev[length - i] = s_to_rev[i];
    // printf("%d   -----    %d\n", (length-i), i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Need your data.

Comment: A string by user, no special character and with space

Comment: You should handle return cases for such functions.

Comment: You don’t need to pre-declare variables. Declare them where you need them, and initialise them with their correct value, not with a bogus (e.g. 0) value. This makes your code both shorter and more readable, and gives less opportunity for invalid values to sneak into your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems. The first, brilliantly spotted by @AKX, is that you write starting from `str[length]` character instead of `str[length-1]` (in C array indexes start from 0).

The second problem is a consequence of the fact you are trying to reverse the string *in place*, that is without using a auxiliary array.

With the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    s_to_rev[length - i] = s_to_rev[i];
}
```

you correctly start updating the last elements of the array. But as soon as you reach the half of the string, the characters at `s_to_rev[i]` are not the original ones anymore, as you updated them previously!

Try instead traversing half the string and swapping characters (just use a temporary `char` variable):

```
for (i = 0; i < length/2; i++) {
    char tmp = s_to_rev[length - i -1],
    s_to_rev[length - i -1] = s_to_rev[i];
    s_to_rev[i]  = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an off-by-one error, since `strlen()` returns the length of the string (e.g. 5 for `hello`), but the last index in the string is 4 (counting from 0).

Try

```
s_to_rev[length - 1 - i] = s_to_rev[i];
```

Comment: ok now it works but don't reverse the string, only half

Comment: Yep, because you're overwriting the second half as you go. That's another bug for you to solve ;-)

Comment: it makes sense, I could fix it starting from length/2, but only if the string is even or not?

Comment: You might want to consider iterating only up to length/2 and swapping characters with each other. :)